# Django project loads in site-packages

Tags: python, django, django-templates, setup.py

After I run setup.py to install a project, the project admin works fine but here's the problem.

Except of the project running from my c:\project.
It's runs from another location at C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\project-0.1-py2.7.egg\project

Why does it clone my project to the site-packages location?
And why does it run from that location instead of my c:/project?

The funny thing is I was able to do a "runserver" from c:\project yet it loads in the site-packages location.

Can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: Django didn't clone it anywhere.  You did.  Python picks up the first module name `project` on the sys.path.  Remove that folder or start using a virtualenvironment.

Comment: Running `python setup.py install` copies the project files in `site-packages`.  For development you either shouldn't install it, install it into a virtualenv, or use setuptools and do `python setup.py develop`.

Comment: Ahh I see. I deleted the folder in site-package and it works fine now.  I need to start learning how virtualenv works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either you chose a name for your project that conflicts with an existing python package and it's merely coincidental, or you somehow managed to build your project as an egg. I'm not sure how you would do that and not realize you had done that, though.

Regardless, check the package to make sure that it is in fact your code and not some other python package. If it's *not* your code, change your project name to avoid the conflict. If it *is* your code, you can simply remove the egg from your 'site-packages' directory. You may have to sudo, though.